# Using other types than QString as literal

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I just learned about [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) and also how it works. This puts all members of QString already into my executable and returns a const reference to it. This will not call the QString constructor.

Now, out of curiosity, I would like to know if I could apply this feature to other data types as well.

I would like to see some QDateTimeLiteral, QTransformLiteral or a QRegularExpressionLiteral ([Maybe all of these types?](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Type-enum)).

Does this make as much sense as a QStringLiteral and would it be easy to implement? Or is there already a Qt fork available that offers me this functionality?

I think there could be issues with implicit shared data holders, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to see such literals so that you can construct an object "for free", i.e. at compile time, then `constexpr` in C++11 is the equivalent applicable to any type that supports it.

Qt also has `Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR` that makes it easier for you because it will expand to `constexpr` if your compiler supports it, but skips it if it doesn't. From Qt 5.5, you have also `Q_DECL_RELAXED_CONSTEXPR` that checks if your compiler supports C++14.

Also note that `QStringLiteral` works in a similar way: if you don't have C++11 enabled, it's not going to actually be a literal - it falls back to  `QString::fromUtf8()` as it relies on lambdas.

Starting from Qt 5.1, they have been adding `constexpr` specifier to some objects, so the easiest way to get a literal is just to try construct some object as `constexpr` and see if it's available for it. I'm not aware of any other options - for example constructors of the objects that you've mentioned take objects with non-trivial constructors as parameters, so I don't think it's possible to create a literal version for them. All of them should be literals in order for it to work: e.g. in case of `QDateTime`, `QDate`, and `QTime` would also have to have their literal version as the constructor takes them as parameters. There are some objects who can't be literals by nature as they rely on dynamic allocation - for each one of the others you would have to write a literal macro. In case of `QStringLiteral` it was easier to make a literal macro as `QString`'s constructor only takes a char array as a parameter.

BTW it puzzles me why they decided to write `QStringLiteral` as a macro instead of making one of `QString` constructors to be constexpr.

Comment: *"it puzzles me why they decided to write QStringLiteral as a macro instead of making one of QString constructors to be constexpr"* - I assume that it was because `QStringLiteral()` exists to eliminate need for dynamic allocation, and `QString(const char *)` needs to work on all `const char*` arguments, not only on string literals, and because of dynamic allocation it couldn't be made `constexpr`.